# What does the number following spawn rate percentage mean?

Tags: hyperrogue

When checking the information for a non-native treasure type you've at least 25 of in a non-hub region, you are informed of the spawn rate of your prize orb.  For example, if you have 50 Ice diamonds in the jungle, the Orb of Flash will be listed as having a spawn rate of 100% as a prize orb.

What confuses me is the number after the spawn rate; for example with 50 gold the text reads "Spawn rate (as prize orb): 100%/2000" in the desert.  What does the 2000 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value given IIRC represents the spawning rate in the Crossroads, for example, "100%/2000" would spawn roughly once per 2000 cells. It is fixed for each Orb type.

In other lands, the situation is more complicated -- some lands have special rules which restrict Orb placement (e.g. Prairie, Caribbean, Red Rock Valley, Ocean), other lands have lots of walls where Orbs cannot spawn in or inaccessible locations where they can spawn but you cannot get there, so "once per XX cells" would not necesssarily be very meaningful anyway. Sometimes it is proportionally adjusted to the native Orb spawn rate, but there are lots of special cases. It is the best to interpret this as a relative number: an orb which says "100%/1000" will spawn twice as frequently as one which says "100%/2000".